# No More Handles Exception for getImage in ColumLabelProvider

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I know that there are several other threads talking on SWT on No More Handles errors, e.g., [SWT No More Handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018553/swt-no-more-handles).

However, I am facing a problem I have when I use a `ColumnLabelProvider` for a `TableViewer` to provide an Image for each Column of the table using the `ColumnLabelProvider.getImage()` method.

The problem appears when I load tables with large amounts of data (e.g., 8000 columns).

I instantiate the different images (only two in my case) as static properties of the View class containing the `TableViewer` to avoid 8000 instances of the same image:

```
private static Image FAILURE_IMAGE = UIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(
        Activator.PLUGIN_ID, "/icons/failure.gif").createImage();

/** {@link Image} used to display a test case as run successfully. */
private static Image OK_IMAGE = UIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(
        Activator.PLUGIN_ID, "/icons/ok.gif").createImage();
```

In the ColumnLabelProvider I simply return these images:

```
public Image getImage(Object element) {
    if (ok)
        return FAILURE_IMAGE;
    else
        return OK_IMAGE;
}
```

However, I get the No More Handles error.

Do I do anything wrong? Is the code to create the Images as static fields bad or faulty?
Shouldn't SWT be able to display tables with 8000 columns having icons.

Comment: OK, sorry, I found the problem. The code above actually works as caching the images as static fields. I had two ColumnLabelProviders within my code and the second one was not using the static fields but created a new Image for each column. Changing the code to the code outlined above solve the problem.

Comment: Post your finding as answer and then accept it.

Comment: its not a good way to declare images as static fields. if the image code throws exception, your entire application breaks. Have a separate cache for resources that you are using and always reuse resources ( font, color..etc)