# STS 3.6.0 Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Has anyone come across a constant  "Unhandled event loop exception in  STS 3.6.0
Environment: Windows 7 64 bit, new high end PC. 32 bit JVM 1.6

If so can you share the fix(s)?

This is a complete fresh download and install of STS 3.6.0, and I have not coded anything yet, just created an integration project. It is a show stopper as it will not allow me to continue. There is not code to debug as I have not coded anything.

Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded STS (eclipse) version 3.6.0, installed, configured internet proxy.
2. Created integration project via boot starter: File->New->Spring starter project.
3. Left all defaults except selected "Integration" checkbox.
4. Created everything OK, downloaded all dependencies from Maven.
5. Ran the project without any changes:  demo->run as->Java App, run OK though empty project of course.
6. I opened Application.java, clicked into it for focus, and hell started.

Had a popup titled "Problem Occurred", with Unhandled event loop exception. No more handles. I hit Ok on popup and second popup appears. Asks if I want to exit workbench as subsequent errors may happen and terminate workbench. Bottom line I am now unable to do anything as popup constantly appears. Same issue exactly on STS version 3.5.1.

I have googled around and seems to happen to LOTS of users but no real resolution.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-07-15 12:54:03.953
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$17(WorkbenchPage.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$3.run(PartServiceImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1453)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4654)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: Is there a (programming) question or is this just a rant?

Comment: What JVM, and is this 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 32 bit JVM 6.1.0.xxx (not at my machine now...)

Comment: It is a rant unless you have a valid reply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SWT No More Handles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018553/swt-no-more-handles)

Comment: See http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/04/17/finding-swt-leaks-with-sleak/

Comment: Thanks David I did see that, however this is a complete fresh download and install of STS 3.6.0, on a new high end machine, and, I have done no "real" coding, only created an integration project. If I have to do anything beyond an environment / configuration change then I won't bother with STS. I should work without issue for such a basic example, so I can only imagine what would happen if I did real coding. I know it is free I would move to intelliJ or even netbeans rather than put up with these issues (bugs).

Comment: OK, so here is the fix, delete eclipse/STS, download IntelliJ, install IntelliJ, as for eclipse...forget about it!

Comment: This looks like a reported Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420561