# SWT memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, swt

I am painting images of a Canvas with a GC (of course) but after I had repainted a new frame with new imaged I need to delete the previous but I don't know how.

I want to dispose the data on the canvas and then redraw the frame but I don't know how.
Anyone knows how can I dispose the data on the canvas without disposing the canvas itself?

Comment: For the memory leak - if you created the GC, did you dispose of it with `GC.dispose()`?  For clearing the canvas, have you tried `Canvas.clearArea()`?

Comment: I have tried to dispose the GC it aint working.

Comment: And  there is no such method clearArea()

Comment: You don't have to dispose of the drawings you make on the Canvas. Your drawing operations are setting pixels in an image, not creating disposable objects. When you say that `GC.dispose()` is not working, what is it not doing that you expect? Sorry, not sure where I pulled `clearArea()` from. You might be interested in `Canvas.drawBackground()`, to paint over your prior drawing. If you're properly disposing the GC if required, your memory leak may be coming from elsewhere. A Java or native heap debugger may help.

Comment: @AssafKaravani What makes you think that you have a memory leak at all?

Comment: Because the program works fine and after several redraws it crashs with the "no more handles"  error

Comment: @AssafKaravani That's why you should post the relevant code and the stacktrace (if any).

Comment: @AssafKaravani - That message tells you that you have too many handles, which may indicate that you have a handle leak. It does not tell you that you have a memory leak. For example, this might be caused by failing to dispose of Fonts, Colors, Images or GCs. More background is provided by the prior question ["SWT No More Handles"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018553/swt-no-more-handles).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to dispose of the old data on the `Canvas`, just use `GC.fillRectangle` to fill the canvas with the background color in your paint listener.

Something like:

```
@Override
public void paint(final PaintEvent event)
{
  Rectangle clientArea = getClientArea();

  GC gc = event.gc;

  gc.setBackground(getBackground());

  gc.fillRectangle(clientArea);

  ... draw your new data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it guys, thank you all!
The problem was that I was creating new Images but wasn't disposing them.